# Is it possible to use a git merge strategy that combines both "subtree" and "ours" functionality?

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to merge a subtree back from parent repo to the subtree-specific repo and instruct git to discard conflicts using "ours". To be more specific I need to discard such conflicts only for specific files. E.g. always use "ours" for a.html but handle other conflicts as usual.

However according to manuals, merge strategies of "subtree" and "ours" are mutually exclusive. Is it possible to achieve that kind of functionality?